# What is the best way to share PC screen with android device through wifi?

Tags: android, android-wifi, apache-mina, screensharing

I need to share my pc screen with my android device over wi-fi. I **kind of** did this by taking continuous screenshots of pc and sending it to the android device(where it will display these images continuously). I used Apache MINA for the connection as well as for sending the images. But as you can guess, this process is slow and it does not look like a video. We can clearly see the drops in images.

**Objective:**

what i need to know is, is there any already existing APIs or methods by which i can STREAM the screen of my pc to the android device through wifi?

Can anybody please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: i read [that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) @Codester . I do not need any help in code, but just which thing (API or a topic) can be used here. Give me a name and I will do the rest. Is your point was anything else? Please feel free to mention. Thanks.

Comment: Usually questions asking for recommendations get closed, that's why I had posted that link.